# CSS How can I make pseudo elements that don't shift the page

Tags: html, css

Hi guys I'm trying to make a fancy style border that kind of highlights a block of text, its basically just two sharp lines that intersect (also gonna make them have a slow animated pulse thats subtlety noticeable, this is the code I have so far:

```
span.fancyTop::before {
    position: relative;
    right: -50px;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    float: right;
    height: 1px;
    background: white;
    z-index: 2;
    content: "";
}

span.fancyRight::after {
    position: relative;
    right: -400px;
    top: -20px;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    float: right;
    z-index: 2;
    background: white;
    height: 200px;
    width: 1px;
    float: right;
}
```

the only problem is it seems to push my content around:

[image]

I want to make it so that I can have the content fit nicely inside the lines but it seems to push it down, I also need it to be responsive for mobile. I'm trying to avoid using absolute positioning and I'd like to be able to use the classes reliably wherever and have the expected result. I'm not a front end designer by any means so any help would be fantastic. Thanks.

Comment: Position the pseudo-elements absolutely...not relatively. That's really the only option..otherwise they **will** affect elements around them.

Comment: @Paulie_D then what happens if I scroll the page or something. Or want to use it on a different element won't the absolute positioning be off??

Comment: Without seeing a demo it's hard to comment. The pseudo-elements would be positioned absolutely *in relation to the parent element*

Comment: Use the element inside a "Container" that also contains the content, and ensure that the container is position: relative, then you can position: absolute the markers / lines, and they will be absolute relative to the container, not the page.

Comment: @Paulie_D - that's not strictly accurate.  They'd be position absolute within the nearest **relatively** positioned parent element.

Comment: @Datsik Have you tried my answer?

Comment: @PraveenKumar yeah worked great. Had to wait a time limit before marking the answer.

Comment: @Datsik Sure no worries buddy. Happy that you got the answer. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements do not take up the DOM Space. So you may use this:

```
span.fancyTop::before {
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
  height: 1px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 2;
  content: "";
}
span.fancyRight::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: -400px;
  top: -20px;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  float: right;
  z-index: 2;
  background: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 1px;
  float: right;
}
```

And make sure you position the parent relatively.

```
span.fancyRight, span.fancyTop {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Using absolutely elements that are LARGER than the parent (relatively positioned) does move the DOM content :-/

Comment: @AlexLaforge Thanks but why digging a post that's 6 years old? 

Comment: Because StackOverflow posts are kept. There must be a core reason. Why trolling my addition?

Comment: @AlexLaforge I am not trolling, but just asked why. Please go ahead and suggest the change, I'm more than happy to approve. Thanks! 

Comment: @AlexLaforge Would you like to update the answer by [edit]ing it now?

Comment: I unfortunately do not know how to improve this answer to take care of larger elements, so my comment is an addition to the answer, not a correction, sorry.

Comment: @AlexLaforge Sure, thanks. I'll include it in the answer, I'll think of some solution, but thanks a lot for the heads up... 

Answer (score 1):

If you change the positioning given to absolute, and add:

```
.fancyTop, .fancyRight { position: relative; }
```

I believe you'll get the result you're looking for. Absolutely-positioned elements are positioned relative to the container it's inside, so long as that container has a position associated with it.

If you want to get really fancy, just change .fancyTop and .fancyRight to .fancy and add the :before and :after pseudoclasses to the one class.

You may run into some other issues with the code you gave, like the span tag is an inline tag. I put together a fiddle for you as an example: https://jsfiddle.net/stgermaniac/p3d0a1ez/